# How to get data from two tables in mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a transaction table and a withdraw table.

I want select the rows from each table that has the same username and the use while to put the results in a table

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE` created_by `= '$user' ";
$result = $db->query($select);
$select1 = "SELECT * FROM withdraw WHERE created_by = '$user' ";
$result1 = $db->query($select1);

if($result->num_rows > 0 || $result1->num_rows > 0  ){
  $id = 0;
               
  while( $row  = $result->fetch_assoc() || $row  = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
    $id ++;
    ?>
    <tr class="purple-border">
      <td><?= $id;?></td>
      <td><?= $row['Type'];?></td>
      <td><?= $row['date'];?></td>
      <td><?= $row['Transaction_id'];?></td>
      <td><?= $row['from_who'];?></td>
      <td><?= $row['to_who'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <style>
    table{
      padding:10px;
    }
                    </style>
  }
```

Comment: If the rows aren't logically joinable, you'll just need to loop separately over each set of results

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: For this you should use `UNION`. Although I also wonder why you have two tables. Why aren't withdrawals in the transaction table? Withdrawals can be indicated with a negative amount or a `type` column that contains either `deposit` or `withdraw`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to select rows from two different tables (transaction and withdraw) based on a common username and then display the results in a table format. You can achieve this by using SQL JOIN and fetching the data in PHP.

```
 <?php
// Assuming you have a valid database connection named $db

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user); // Sanitize the user input

$select = "SELECT t.*, w.* 
           FROM transaction t 
           JOIN withdraw w ON t.created_by = w.created_by
           WHERE t.created_by = '$user'";

$result = $db->query($select);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $id = 0;
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Type (Transaction)</th>
            <th>Date (Transaction)</th>
            <th>Transaction ID (Transaction)</th>
            <th>From Who (Transaction)</th>
            <th>To Who (Transaction)</th>
            <th>Type (Withdraw)</th>
            <th>Date (Withdraw)</th>
            <!-- Add more column headers for withdraw table here -->
        </tr>
        <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id++;
            ?>
            <tr class="purple-border">
                <td><?= $id; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Type']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['Transaction_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['from_who']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['to_who']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['withdraw_type']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['withdraw_date']; ?></td>
                <!-- Add more columns from the withdraw table here -->
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
<?php
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
```

Please make sure to replace withdraw_type, withdraw_date, and other column names from the withdraw table with the actual column names you have in your database.

Comment: This will join everything created by the user to everything else created by the same user in the other table. I doubt that is the intention, it is unlikely to make any logical sense